# Different options to write delegate reference swift

Tags: swift, xcode, option-type, uiapplicationdelegate

I was trying to create a function delegate to pass data from `MainViewController` to `SecondViewController`. I set the protocol:

```
protocol PassDataDelegate: AnyObject {
    func passData(data: [String])
}
```

I added the delegate function to the SecondViewController:

```
func passData(data: [String]) {
   //Pass Data
}
```

I set delegate to MainViewController:

```
weak var delegate: PassDataDelegate?
```

Here when the button is tapped the delegate function is called:

```
@objc func buttonTapped() {
    guard let vcdelegate = delegate else {return}
    vcdelegate.passData(data: data)
}
```

There are two options to write the delegate reference:

## Option 1

I write in MainViewController the reference of delegate to the SecondViewController:

```
let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
self.delegate = secondViewController
```

It works like I aspected.

## Option 2

I write in SecondViewController:

```
let vc = MainViewController()
vc.delegate = self
```

The problem is that delegate is still nil, I don't understand why. Any hints? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In option 2

```
let vc = MainViewController()
```

you create a new instance other than the real presented one so leaving the real delegate = nil

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about it